# ExpressJS 3.2 renders blank pages sometimes

Tags: node.js, express

I just upgraded to Express 3.2.4. It works fine, but sometimes (actually, quite frequently) renders a blank page. There is no error, response status is 200, but there is no response body.

It does this with every view, including those using only a simple res.send('somestring') call. Sometimes "somestring" appears in the browser, but mostly it just shows a blank page.

Any ideas about why this is happening? The same code worked fine with Express 2.5.9, and Express is the only node module I updated

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I'm using NodeJS 0.10.2 and the SWIG template engine (via ConsolidateJS).

An example:

```
some: function(req, res) {

    res.send('some text');

},
```

Comment: You need to post more context. What is `some` a key of? How are you handling routes? What middleware are you using? A minimal example might be useful (for yourself too, by stripping away parts of your app you might run into the problem). Also, if possible, try a more recent version of Node (0.10.7).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, it is solved now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question :)

Indeed this was a middleware issue.

The problem was caused by connect-gzip. I replaced it with the built-in express.compress() and now everything works fine.

Thanks!